# Rain in Unity3d Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, weather

I am trying to add rain to my game I have made a particle emitter, a rain material and all of that stuff. The only issue is whenever the rain comes the game's framerate starts to drop until the game is unplayable because of the rains particles. Is there any way that I can optimize a particle emitter or should I use something else to make rain?

Comment: Google Unity 3d rain.

Comment: @Sorceri Whenever I look it up all it shows is using a particle emitter on a small map.

Comment: Need more information on what you have done so far. Such as what settings the particle system has. If you have one big particle system covering the whole map with a very large max particles setting, then the performance will drop fast due to the large amount of particles alive at once.